# Prestashop 1.7 issue with "reset" "Exception thrown by module [module name] on install" and cannot find class_index.php,

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I read many similar issues about "reset", or "uninstall" and "install" of a module being in development in Prestashop 1.7 (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996528/how-to-remove-override-when-uninstalling-the-module-in-prestashop) or [there](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/238197-solved-overrides-not-working-anymore-in-154/)).

Basicaly I have overridden files in `[prestashop project]/modules/[custom module]/override/classes/` and `[prestashop project]/modules/[custom module]/override/controllers/front/`. All my files respect convention:

```
<?php
class [Class to be overridden] extends [Class to be overridden]Core {
        ....
}
?>
```

In `[prestashop project]/override/classes/` or `[prestashop project]/override/controllers/front/` my files are copied from `[prestashop project]/modules/[custom module]/override/...` often with mistakes: like bracket {} mitakes (not existing in the source file) that are not opened/closed correctly making the class useless.

So, I delete manually the miscopied files in `[prestashop project]/override/...` and launch some "reset" action.

I'll add, that after manual delete I often see this issue in the Symfony log when trying to "reset" the custom module:

> Exception thrown by module [module name] on install. Class [overriden file]OverrideOriginal_remove[some char chain] does not exist.

As explained in `[prestashop project]/override/readme_override.txt`:

> Frequently Asked Questions
>
> Q: I added an override file but it seems to be ignored by PrestaShop
>   A: You need to trigger the regeneration of the /cache/class_index.php file. This is done simply by deleting the file. It is the same when manually removing an override: in order to reinstate the default behavior, you must delete the /cache/class_index.php file.

**But `[prestashop project]/cache/class_index.php` does not exists in Prestashop 1.7.**

Answer (score 0):

In Prestashop 1.7, `class_index.php` files are located in:
`[prestashop project]/app/cache/dev` or 
`[prestashop project]/app/cache/prod` according if the project is set either in "dev" or "prod" mode.

Answer (score 0):

For overriding a class in Prestashop 1.7 you have to copy the class file in `[module_name]/override/classes` directory during the module installation, and remove it on uninstall.

This is explained in further detail [here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/overrides/#overriding-a-class).